# Reading URL image content from HTTPResponse in Python

Tags: python, image, google-colaboratory, httpresponse, imageurl

I have an image URL in the form of a shareable [Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z33YPsoMe0lSNNa2XWa0tiK2571j2tFu/view?usp=sharing) that I would like to access in my Python script. Below is what I have been trying:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests

img = Image.open(requests.get(URL).raw)
```

However I know this returns an HTTPResponse. I have already consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460305/getting-an-image-from-an-httpresponse) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291934/accessing-an-image-in-an-httpresponse) thread to no avail. How do I get rid of all the other content in the URL and just keep the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your URL of `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###fileId###/view?usp=sharing`, this file is not publicly shared. When you want to use the URL of this file, please publicly share it.
- `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###fileId###/view?usp=sharing` of "webViewLink" is not the direct link. In this case, please use "webContentLink" like `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###fileId###"`.
- I think that it is required to modify `requests.get(URL).raw` of `Image.open(requests.get(URL).raw)` to BytesIO.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please replace `###fileId###` of `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###fileId###` with your file ID.

```py
from PIL import Image
import requests
import io

URL = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###fileId###"
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(URL).content))
print(img.format, img.size, img.mode)
```

- I could confirm that when the file of `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###fileId###` is publicly shared, the script works.

#### Reference:

- [Resource representations of Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations)

Comment: It should be accessible now! Let me know if not :)

Comment: @timpanists Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should just set the `stream` parameter of `requests.get()` method to True

```
 class requests.Response

    The Response object, which contains a server’s response to an HTTP request.
    
        raw = None

        File-like object representation of response (for advanced usage). 
        Requires that `stream=True` on the request.
```

[requests.request documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.2.3/api/#requests.request)

Solution:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests

img = Image.open(requests.get(URL, stream=True).raw)
```